# Don't match string in specific context

Tags: c#, .net, regex

For my internship I've been asked to create a tool that creates a regular expression from a few examples. Now I got it working, it generates multiple regular expressions and they are sorted depending on how greedy they are, but I want more.

The regex generator works by replacing parts of a string with regular expression character classes. For example `GOM178` would turn into `[A-Z]+178`(letters replaced) or `GOM\d+` (numbers replaced). The hard part is getting multiple character classes in one. For example at one point `\p{P}` is tried as well, and it replaces `[],/\-` and more. That causes the other character classes to mess up. It would turn `[A-Z]` in `\p{P}A\p{P}Z\p{P}`. Replacing `\p{P}` before `[A-Z]` wouldn't work as well, because that would replace the `P` in `\p{P}` causing this: `\p{[A-Z]}`.

I've already tried negative lookaheads, but that didn't workout too well. The only reason why it currently works is because I test it before saving the result. This is the regular expression I've used for that:

```
(?:(?!(?:\[a-z\]|\[A-Z\]|\[a-zA-Z\]|\\d\+\[\\\.,\]\?\\d\*|\\d|\\s|\\p\{P\}|\\w|\\n|\.)(?:\*|\?|\+|\+\?|\*\?)?)(<The character class to match goes here>))
```

Here is an example of the regex in action: [Link to example](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3a(%3f!(%3f%3a%5c%5ba-z%5c%5d%7c%5c%5bA-Z%5c%5d%7c%5c%5ba-zA-Z%5c%5d%7c%5c%5cd%5c%2b%5c%5b%5c%5c%5c.%2c%5c%5d%5c%3f%5c%5cd%5c*%7c%5c%5cd%7c%5c%5cs%7c%5c%5cp%5c%7bP%5c%7d%7c%5c%5cw%7c%5c%5cn%7c%5c.)(%3f%3a%5c*%7c%5c%3f%7c%5c%2b%7c%5c%2b%5c%3f%7c%5c*%5c%3f)%3f)(%5cp%7bP%7d%2b))&i=%5ba-z%5df%2f-).
As you can see it also matches the `-` and `]` in the character class. It should ignore it because it's part of `[a-z]` which is noted in the negative lookahead.

Long story short, a string should not be replaced when it's in a specific context. Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this, or perhaps have a better idea on how to do this.

Comment: But the thing I want to check is if it isn't part of a character class. If I wouldn't escape [ and ] that would make the regex check if the string isn't part of the letters A through Z, not if it isn't part of the string "[A-Z]"

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. What do you need to fix, what are example results? Please provide an [MVCE (minimal complete verifiable example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear enough. Currently when trying to replace "\p{P}" (punctuation) in "[A-Z]15" it matches the [, - and ]. That would mean "[A-Z]15" would turn into "\p{P}A\p{P}Z\p{P}15". That's an invalid regular expression.

Comment: Do you mean you need to subtract those sumbols from `\p{P}` class completely ([`[\p{P}-[][-]]`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b%5cp%7bP%7d-%5b%5d%5b-%5d%5d&i=%2c.%5d%5b-()!%40%23)), or to only ignore them in specific contexts? Do not use regex101.com for .NET regex testing, it does not support all .NET regex features.

Comment: Yes, they need to be ignored in specific contexts. Thanks for the link. I've changed my example to it, but the matched result was the same

Comment: When you're creating the regex, you should have each construct as partof an array/list... when you want to replace it, you don't replace 1 char, but the whole item

Comment: @Mariano I'm not completely sure what you mean. Could you elaborate? As I understand it now you want to replace a while string at once: `GOM17` to `[A-Z]+d+`

I've already tried something similar, but it resulted in a failure. Perhaps some pseudo-code?

Comment: Nevermind, I probably misunderstood your question. Honestly, it's not pretty clear what you're trying to do... I'd edit the question if I were you.

Comment: I'm now really sure how to word it differently. I've changed the question a little, but it's not too different from before. Perhaps the example would shed some light?